# Blender Will Not Select Faces, Vertices, or Edges in edit mode individually

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, selection-tools

Recently in Blender 2.75 I've come face to face with an inability to select the proper faces, edges or vertices in edit mode individually.

Selecting everything with the <kbd>A</kbd> button is no problem, but when I right click on a vertex, face, or edge in their respective selection modes, there's no orange highlight and no manipulator around the selected face/edge/vertex, which means I have no way of selecting an individual mesh piece in edit mode.

I've even tried the lasso tool and selecting stuff by pressing the <kbd>C</kbd> button and clicking.

I didn't have this problem until I changed my Intel graphics driver to display color in 16 bit. Except I only changed it to fix another problem in blender which made the viewport lag one step behind every action, like clicking on an object or dragging or moving something around.

I'd love to know if there's any way to fix this problem and if there's still a way to keep blender from lagging like it did before. I look forward to seeing your answers.

Comment: try to find updated drivers for your graphics card.

Comment: See: https://www.blender.org/manual/troubleshooting/3d_view.html#invalid-selection

Comment: Might see if changing your graphics driver setting back to the way it was fixes this. Then you would know for sure that there is a link and not just a coincidence. Also it may help if you post your full system specs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem on a Mac, trying to use a keyboard shortcut for right clicking individual faces, and the problem was solved for me by simply enabling a secondary mouse click in my general settings.